# Keeping two elements in view while sliding up using Jquery or Keep one element from scrolling during transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two elements on the same line one that is floated left and another floated right in a contained div. Basically a sidebar that is floated right and a content box that is floated left.

I'm using Jquery keypress navigation to deal with links that are placed in the sidebar(right) that on-clicking would slide up content on the content box left.

However, during the transition of sliding content on the content box(left), the (right) element which is the sidebar goes up all the way to the top & then settles when the transition ends, which mean it actually hides then displays during the transition as the page scroll to retrieve content.
it will always adjust the dimensions after revealing the content box on the right.

It's very simple in layout, I'm just providing a brief description.
Anyone have an idea how to keep the right element static?

**EDIT:** Added Preview on Plunker.
[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/SmwpSCajEFuvyLSGfRFR?p=preview)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
// hides all DIVs with the CLASS container
// and displays the one with the ID 'home' only
$(".container").css("display","none");
$("#home").css("display","block");

// makes the navigation work after all containers have bee hidden 
showViaLink($("aside button#navigation a"));

// listens for any navigation keypress activity
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    switch(e.which)
    {
        // user presses the "a"
        case 97:    showViaKeypress("#home");
                    break;  

        // user presses the "s" key
        case 115:   showViaKeypress("#about");
                    break;

        // user presses the "d" key
        case 100:   showViaKeypress("#contact");
                    break;

        // user presses the "f" key
        case 102:   showViaKeypress("#awards");
                    break;

        // user presses the "g" key 
        case 103:   showViaKeypress("#links");
    }
});
});

// shows a given element and hides all others
function showViaKeypress(element_id)
{
$(".container").css("display","none");
// if multiple keys are pressed rapidly this will hide all but the last pressed key's div
$(".container").hide(1);
$(element_id).slideDown("slow");
}

// shows proper DIV depending on link 'href'
function showViaLink(array)
{
array.each(function(i)
{   
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".container").css("display","none");
        $(target).slideDown("slow");
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Please add a JSFIDDLE or PLUNKER for it. thanks

Comment: [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/SmwpSCajEFuvyLSGfRFR?p=preview) , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you needed. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EgctEA7Fucr3T6jfvs0m?p=preview)

```
aside {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
}
```

and html formatting is done (removed some flying `<div>` tag) and your `styles` need some work.

Comment: Thank a lot, I did apply your styles on aside, However now the sidebar keep scrolling as the user scroll and that is not what i wanted to achieve. I just want the sidebar keeping static as the user click on the link to retrieve content. Also can you please specify what my styles need? as I'm just a beginner. Thanks again

Comment: Well I guess you can reproduce my issue.